# Define a custom ordering criteria in the relations() method

Tags: database, sorting, yii, relation

I have a model `A` that has a relationship of type `HAS_MANY` with model `B`.

`B`'s attributes are:

```
id,
user_id,
message,
date,
parent_message_id
```

I need elements of model `B` to be ordered by date (descending), but in case the `parent_message_id` is different from null, the date to be taken into consideration should be the date corresponding to `parent_message_id`.

Is it possible to customize the criteria used to order the relation?

Comment: can you test for the condition first and use a different relation or scope depending on the result?

Comment: @ldg I am not quite sure if i get what you mean, could you be a little more specific? Or provide an example? Most thankful for your reply!

Comment: If you want to change the sort order of all the results and can test for whatever condition that may require, you can add a scope as appropriate to change the sort order. It may or may not make sense for your need, see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-named-scopes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, i solved this the following way: model A HAS_MANY model B, therefore, i redefined the relationships method to the following:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'messages' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'WallMessages', 'liga_id',
            'condition'=>'specific_post.parent_message_id IS NULL', 
            'order'=>'specific_post.date DESC', 
            'alias'=>'specific_post'),
    );
}
```

Therefore, I only compare the date of those messages with no parent id. The downside is that I have to access each post's "child messages"... but well, couldn't find another workaround. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only possible to sort elements according to the same column. However there might be a database ninja that could help you.

In an perfect world you could use the [afterFind()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail) method for any customization at any level, not only sorting, but also changing some values for others. It is not as fast as a plan order, maybe, but this way you release the MySQL server from a little load. Plus it is called automatically. Cheers

Comment: I looked into your suggestion but couldn't manage to solve it this way! Thanks anyway @Kor

Comment: No problem, mate. Hopefully you could manage to find a solution. Good luck ;)